# How to stop all auto workers with shortcut?

Tags: civilization-5

I seem to recall in Civ4 there was a keyboard short cut to break all workers on the map  out of automatic mode. Is there a similar command for civ5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is, at least not in the base game.  I've never seen one referenced in-game.  I checked the [manual](http://cdn.steampowered.com/Manuals/8930/Civ_V_Manual_English_Updated.pdf?t=1322330023) (page 207, click the link "Keyboard Shortcuts" from the Table of Contents) as well as a [couple of](http://segmentnext.com/2010/09/23/civilization-v-hotkeys-keyboard-shortcuts-guide/) [third-party sites](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Civilization-V.html).

I found this "[Light Touch](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=426849)" mod which gives you a bit more control over worker automation. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it might take some of the frustration out of worker automation.